# WordPress : Sitemap contains spam url

Tags: wordpress, sitemap, yoast

I am using Yoast plugin to generate sitemap for my website but I don't know why it contains a lot of spam or unwanted urls..

http://eenfotech.com/sitemap_index.xml

I tried several things

1. Disable all existing plugin and try to generate sitemap
2. Delete cache before generating

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this problem in the Yoast-SEO plugin. In this plugin, you can manage all content type which currently exists. I hope it would help you out. Please follow the below URL:

{DOMAIN_NAME}/wp-admin/admin.php?page=wpseo_titles#top#post-types

see below-attached screenshot:

[image]

Comment: I think you misunderstood the problem. Problem is I am getting URl's in sitemap that are not part of my websites. What you want me to change?

Answer (score 0):

There is URL problem too. Some of the links are 'http://eenfotech.comE:\HostingSpaces...'

I would check everything for malware first. Check your WordPress root directory if there is something suspicious. Check theme files too.